# Start an Android Wear app with a "Start ..." voice action different from the app's name

Tags: android, android-manifest, wear-os, voice-recognition

I have an app with a difficult name that the system's built-in speech recognizer is not able to properly understand. For this reason, assuming that my app is called **X**, I would like to be able to launch it by saying "Start **Y**."

As described in the [official documentation](http://developer.android.com/training/wearables/apps/voice.html#AppProvided), the name of the app is defined in the manifest:

```
<application
    ...
    android:label="X" > ... </application>
```

while the text to say after the "Start" command is defined here:

```
<activity
    ...
    android:label="Y" > ... </activity>
```

However in doing so the name of the app in the app list becomes **Y**, while I would like it to remain **X**...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only thing you can do is to use an activity alias with a different label. In this case the user will see two icons in the list.

Comment: Is there a way to use the alias and hide the entry from the list?

Comment: No, it's not possible

Comment: I've added in the app's manifest `<activity-alias android:name="Y" android:targetActivity=".MainActivity" />`, but in the app list now I see twice *X*, and Google Now does not respond to voice command "Start *Y*." Have I done something wrong?

Comment: Same with `<activity-alias android:name="Y" android:label="Y" android:targetActivity=".MainActivity" />`...

Comment: Solved in this way: `<activity-alias android:label="Y" android:name=".Y" android:targetActivity=".MainActivity" ><intent-filter><action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/><category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/></intent-filter></activity-alias>`. Thanks!